# using eval for a int not a control, or what do i use instead of eval?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I pass some datarow fields multiple times in a few functions to get some result for my table, so i thought id put them in some int's make the code clean, but the below returns

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

and if i use <%# instead i get expected ")" (right bracket)

what do i need to use to make the below work?

Thanks

```
<%
    C = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Confidentiality"));
    I = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Integrity"));
    A = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Availability"));
    T = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Threat"));
    V = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Vulnerability"));
    L = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Likelihood"));
%>

<td class='<%# functions.colorscale(functions.Importance(C,I,A))%>'><%# functions.Importance(C,I,A) %></td>
<td class='<%# functions.colorscale(functions.Rank(C,I,A,T,V,L))%>'><%# functions.Rank(C,I,A,T,V,L) %></td>
<td class='<%# functions.colorscale(Eval("NewRank").ToString())%>'><%# Eval("NewRank") %></td>
```

Comment: What's the context around the code you've shown?  Is that inside a GridView or something?  If not, where are "Confidentiality", etc defined?

Comment: its in a reapater that is databound via codebehind to a datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i needed to put each var in its own <% now it works!

```
            <%# C = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Confidentiality")) %>
            <%# I = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Integrity")) %>
            <%# A = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Availability")) %>
            <%# T = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Threat")) %>
            <%# V = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Vulnerability")) %>
            <%# L = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Likelihood")) %>
```